# Собрать данные в один объект из нескольких запросов RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular, angular4, rxjs

На OnInitе нужно иметь массив:

```
 let finalArray = [
 {code:7865, price:203, color: red},
 {code:8865, price:303, color: pink},
 ...]
```

Из запроса на url1 получаем массив объектов по количеству которых, забрав из каждого его id, делаем дополнительные запросы на url2, получаем значения для  'price' и 'color'.

Как собрать весь объект с code, price и color, если code приходит с url1 ?

```
 finalArray = [];
  this.httpService.getDataFromServer(url1)
    .pipe(
      map(resp => {
        // здесь приходит 'code'
        const ordersArray = [];
        for (const items of resp) {
          ordersArray.push(items.id);
        }
        return ordersArray;
      }),
      switchMap(data => {
        return forkJoin(
          data.map((order) => {
            return this.httpService.getDataFromServer(url2 + '/' + order);
          })
        );
      })
    ).subscribe(resp => {
      const arr = [];
      for (const patient of resp) {
        const object = {};
        object['price'] = patient.price;
        object['color'] = patient.color;
        arr.push(object);
      }
      this.finalArray = arr;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов решения данной проблемы на самом деле не очень много, один из - это кешировать в какой-то переменной объявленной выше перед запросом, другой вариант сделать все более реактивно используя просто маппинг потока:

```
this.httpService.getDataFromServer(url1).pipe(
    map((response) => {
        // здесь приходит `code`
        const orders = [];
        const codes = [];
        for (const item of response) {
            orders.push(item.id);
            // также пушим в отдельный массив наш `code`
            codes.push(item.code);
        }
        // а здесь возвращаем уже не массив `orders`,
        // а объект с `{ orders: [], codes: [] }`
        return { orders, codes };
    }),
    switchMap(({ orders, codes }) => {
        orders = orders.map((order) => this.httpService.getDataFromServer(url2 + '/' + order));
        return forkJoin(orders).pipe(
            // а здесь маппим на объект `{ codes: [], patients: [] }`
            map((patients) => ({ codes, patients }))
        );
    })
).subscribe(({ codes, patients }) => {
    for (let i = 0, length = patients.length; i < length; i++) {
        const { price, color } = patients[i];
        const code = codes[i];
        this.finalArray.push({ price, color, code });
    }
});
```

Я к сожалению не знаю ваших моделей и что возвращает ваш сервер, так что делал немного наобум, делая предположение из вашего кода, если что - отпишитесь.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! Логика понятна, приеду,  попробую применить на реальном коде.

Answer (score 0):

с forkJoin может быть проблема, так как он параллельно запускает сразу все запросы, они могут быть отклонены сервером. Например массив из 300 ордеров, отошлет 300 запросов разом. Сервер может это воспринять как DDOS атака. ???

Могу предложить код хелпера для последовательных запросов, они будут правда выполнятся дольше. Каждый следующий будет выполнен тогда, когда придет ответ от предыдущего.

Допустим, ecть массив из 300 ордеров: const orders: Order = [.....];
Нужно сделать последовательно 300 запросов.

```
const request: SingleRequest<Order, Patient> = (order: Order) => {
  return this.httpService.getDataFromServer(url2 + '/' + order));
};

return ConsequenceRequestsHelper.doRequests$<Order, Patient>(orders, request).pipe(
   map((patients) => // .... )
);
```

Код хелпера (универсально, пригодится еще где-нибудь):

```
// нужен для последовательного выполнения запросов
// если запустить combineLatest или forkJoin может упасть

export type SingleRequest<TRequestItem, TResponseItem> = (item: TRequestItem) => 
Observable<TResponseItem[]>;

export class ConsequenceRequestsHelper {

static doRequests$<TRequestItem, TResponseItem>(
     requestItems: TRequestItem[], singleRequest$: SingleRequest<TRequestItem, TResponseItem>): Observable<TResponseItem[]> {

     const responseItems: TResponseItem[] = [];
     return this.doRequest(requestItems, responseItems, singleRequest$);
}

private static doRequest<TRequestItem, TResponseItem>(
                    requestItems: TRequestItem[],
                    responseItems: TResponseItem[],
                    singleRequest$: SingleRequest<TRequestItem, TResponseItem>
 ): Observable<TResponseItem[]> {

       const currentRequestItem: TRequestItem = requestItems.shift();
       if (!currentRequestItem) { // если закончились запросы
         return of(responseItems);
       } else {
         return singleRequest$(currentRequestItem).pipe( // выбрали параметр запроса, делаем запрос TODO: а если ошибка
             switchMap((responseItems2: TResponseItem[]) => {  // получили ответ
                 const newResponseItems = [...responseItems, ... responseItems2]; // соединили ответы в массив
                 return this.doRequest(requestItems, newResponseItems, singleRequest$); // делаем следующий запрос
             })
         )
       }

    }
 }
```